# Calling a method of a class, the classname is a variable

Tags: python

I came up with this solution. But this looks too complicated. There must be a better and easier way.   And second : is there a way to dynamically import the class ?

```
class_name = "my_class_name"                # located in the module : my_class_name.py  
import my_class_name from my_class_name          

my_class = globals()[class_name]  
object = my_class()  
func = getattr(my_class,"my_method")
func(object, parms)                         # and finally calling the method with some parms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `__import__` built-in function. It does exactly what you expect it to do.

Edit: as promised, here's an example. Not a very good one, I just kinda got bad news and my head is elsewhere, so you'd probably write a smarter one with more practical application for your context. At least, it illustrates the point.

```
>>> def getMethod(module, cls, method):
...     return getattr(getattr(__import__(module), cls), method)
... 
>>> getMethod('sys', 'stdin', 'write')
<built-in method write of file object at 0x7fcd518fa0c0>
```

Edit 2: here's a smarter one.

```
>>> def getMethod(path):
...     names = path.split('.')
...     return reduce(getattr, names[1:], __import__(names[0]))
... 
>>> getMethod('sys.stdin.write')
<built-in method write of file object at 0x7fdc7e0ca0c0>
```

Are you still around?

Comment: Gimme a moment, I'll write an example and post it

Comment: I tried to understand your answer and find out how to make it work. Fi, if I have an external function, instead of a class method, this works fine and looks easy :
`object = __import(module)
getattr(object, "my_function")`

Comment: `object = __import__(module)  
    getattr(object, "my_function")  
  `

Comment: :) great! problem solved. You can one-line that with `f = getattr(__import__(modname), funname)`